Can the Participation of a Particular Partial Signature in an Aggregated (MuSig/MuSig2) Signature Be Proven?
Assume the following setup:

A publicly known message (it could be any message, or even empty).
The message is signed by 3 keypairs, each using a deterministic nonce value.
The signatures are aggregated into a single aggregated signature.
The public keys are aggregated into a single aggregated public key.
All information is public except for the complete set of keypairs and partial signatures that contributed to the aggregated signature and aggregated public key.

The question is: Given the available public information, is it possible to verify whether a specific partial signature contributed to the aggregated signature?

To make the question more concrete, I believe it's best to present a practical example. The following outlines all the data that is publicly available in this scenario:
message: 45F8481247B5C84C48A9952CC7B9AA9B27EAD6A90B2D250E24F81152FB25DECE
deterministicNonce: 6942F99EDEE91D2B59780FC865016CC7F452973C3D7A8735AE9F76CAACB57C1A

Keypair 1 (publicly known data in this scenario):
  privateKey: 6942F99EDEE91D2B59780FC865016CC7F452973C3D7A8735AE9F76CAACB57CCD
  secp256k1PublicKey: 02A3D48DC0B2BA69F340F68FB4D8BEEF5BE361FB64DAB71EF74ACCF6ACABF70B01
  secp256k1MusigPublicNonce: F57A3DA0D4A492010CF9777E237D4EA7005212072958248A624E761F70A0027AD78EB2A99784232661BEFD6CA2CF17517E49DAFFD7AA6C5BD69FE93A4FC841CB835123BC3404FB9CBEC7BA112C6D0F6800247DB3382619DA497D11E08869DD926DE9457DEF6E9B9197BD44A5DF599CD0260851F0707C693B8FBE58914C1A219BBE888765
  secp256k1MusigSecretNonce: 220EDCF13B5E1B766BF04082984E34CD17575158C7F7F25DC4A81D1C0A9A8E7E33CAD3BD00A362F6E9AF37DC10EAE6162C6FDF8C0074A050025CD1BB0D2BF14010DB8722010BF7ABACF6CC4AF71EB7DA64FB61E35BEFBED8B48FF640F369BAB2C08DD4A340C4EB116E73B2F1C7B4D2FB188BAB910934212CAF70F1175228FAC79D8F5488
  secp256k1MusigPartialSignature: EBFB1A3284DDE05BA570956916623030D11F266A8260A8C4F074190793F088E12EABB41F

Keypair 2 (not publicly known data in this scenario):
  privateKey: 6942F99EDEE91D2B59780FC865016CC7F452973C3D7A8735AE9F76CAACB57E4A
  secp256k1PublicKey: 027FA2874F02C66B1B7778FD178E8332CF113FDB5536F2005E83DD1F6E77037A89
  secp256k1MusigPublicNonce: F57A3DA05150DF05A15EE6CECB86218C9300090AF710EB2B8C6E51CBF3D0B8EB7235E240249F1B51F53F956FA4609B707AED531CCB37854A8FB9AB0E703CDB34BCABA310846018549CE3086CCB7BB0DC25ABB59D79205D918F6911EBF1B10AFE1516CB7F849E04BA945332881E13A3E5C63AC05120F52FABD248F03D5A5D45ECBEC37538
  secp256k1MusigSecretNonce: 220EDCF12372A9189B273F7EE4E6D63CF919F3735C93AE0D4898F2099F986CA572097D2BB6C5A742EDE67454BD1F20B2071A6772529F7EC8815E817BA33A51BFD9BD2B6A897A03776E1FDD835E00F23655DB3F11CF32838E17FD78771B6BC6024F87A27FF224968B7AE9ECD15FCE3965A05C6E90C78D8527F01744204BE48161B6FEA8C7
  secp256k1MusigPartialSignature: EBFB1A321C984FD7C278DC61F18C80A68DA4B231B08337C39A6F508E27EA184989190027

Keypair 3 (not publicly known data in this scenario):
  privateKey: 6942F99EDEE91D2B59780FC865016CC7F452973C3D7A8735AE9F76CAACB58011
  secp256k1PublicKey: 024CBBD03BC9B079BC360A26A034A298EB4520333F87DA4A3D195F390B50B7BD27
  secp256k1MusigPublicNonce: F57A3DA0D30E12A1367AE49B87EAA99FA678DEAD817221DBAC9BB0AFA70D9A08AB36B147D3B03A46C163E0401898FA6D209B6F139680A4E95D07A9A4E501106725C1671B8B916792FBE092441290E2300FC5C093DD40118D29DFF8F25A9C7413B4D86D26E75DAD92CD3A94455B9DDD94673F283B7E0438652FA5FCC91B03C3B44DA39130
  secp256k1MusigSecretNonce: 220EDCF1E48E62BE3329485818C71B5D129F0294E3C7E899AA584B6940FD9737CFDD2EE3483F714997C706C3F984E35CB405F869E3D477EA479E42B300C0EC82B145F0D027BDB7500B395F193D4ADA873F332045EB98A234A0260A36BC79B0C93BD0BB4C940202A0A14E78D617DD2CD39E62C10A2D43EBC66E5962179C7C85D062401979
  secp256k1MusigPartialSignature: EBFB1A32894F0D7D27ACE83FD53B0E14B3F65F963BB62F1F1F29B89B25E5DF3B96174160

Aggregated Data:
  secp256k1XonlyPublicKeyAggregated: 6BF1779F97025AFD66240B3CDDB97DED15B6D44902CBDC98FE8BA5E18F4F37A894B88F128CDDFB02C265154E17E30D09D82A5528F123046235124D34E2F8262C
  aggregatedSignature: BE99342E3F9A4F4EDC5815C90270B32D29DB7B7F65F39DE33FCFA82E9C19EA6B2AC53DB08F965A0ADD29BEEC12BA3833B3EB32C0FAC481F521EE21D97DA5B465

If it is possible to prove participation for a partial signature, then as a corollary, given the data above, what specific operations are required to confirm that the secp256k1MusigPartialSignature EBFB1A3284DDE05BA570956916623030D11F266A8260A8C4F074190793F088E12EABB41F contributed to the aggregatedSignature BE99342E3F9A4F4EDC5815C90270B32D29DB7B7F65F39DE33FCFA82E9C19EA6B2AC53DB08F965A0ADD29BEEC12BA3833B3EB32C0FAC481F521EE21D97DA5B465?

As a reference, the following illustrative code demonstrates how the above data was generated using the secp256k1 library.
secp256k1_keypair secp256k1Keypair{};
if (secp256k1_keypair_create(
        Secp256k1::context().get(), &secp256k1Keypair, privateKey) == 0)
  throw std::runtime_error{"failed to create keypair"};
}

secp256k1_pubkey secp256k1PublicKey{};
if (secp256k1_keypair_pub(
        Secp256k1::context().get(), &secp256k1PublicKey,
        &secp256k1Keypair) == 0) {
  throw std::runtime_error{"failed to extract public key"};
}

secp256k1_musig_secnonce secp256k1MusigSecretNonce{};
secp256k1_musig_pubnonce secp256k1MusigPublicNonce{};
if (secp256k1_musig_nonce_gen(
        Secp256k1::context().get(), &secp256k1MusigSecretNonce,
        &secp256k1MusigPublicNonce, deterministicValue, nullptr,
        &secp256k1PublicKey, message, nullptr, nullptr) == 0) {
  throw std::runtime_error{"failed to generate nonces"};
}

secp256k1_musig_keyagg_cache secp256k1MusigKeyAggregationCache{};
// ... code to aggregate the public keys ...

secp256k1_musig_aggnonce secp256k1MusigAggregatedNonce{};
// ... code to aggregate the public nonces ...

secp256k1_musig_session secp256k1MusigSession{};
if (secp256k1_musig_nonce_process(
        Secp256k1::context().get(), &secp256k1MusigSession,
        &secp256k1MusigAggregatedNonce, message,
        &secp256k1MusigKeyAggregationCache) == 0) {
  throw std::runtime_error{"failed to process nonce"};
}

if (secp256k1_musig_partial_sign(
        Secp256k1::context().get(), &secp256k1MusigPartialSignature,
        &secp256k1MusigSecretNonce, &secp256k1Keypair,
        &secp256k1MusigKeyAggregationCache,
        &secp256k1MusigSession) == 0) {
  throw std::runtime_error{"failed to partially sign"};
}

const constexpr std::size_t schnorrSignatureSize{64};
CryptoArray<schnorrSignatureSize> aggregatedSignature{};
// ... code to aggregate the partial signatures ...
secp256k1_pubkey secp256k1AggregatedPublicKey;
if (secp256k1_musig_pubkey_get(
        Secp256k1::context().get(), &secp256k1AggregatedPublicKey,
        &secp256k1MusigKeyAggregationCache) == 0) {
  throw std::runtime_error{"failed to get aggregated public key"};
}

secp256k1_xonly_pubkey secp256k1XonlyPublicKeyAggregated{};
if (secp256k1_xonly_pubkey_from_pubkey(
        Secp256k1::context().get(), & secp256k1XonlyPublicKeyAggregated,
        nullptr, &secp256k1AggregatedPublicKey) == 0) {
  throw std::runtime_error{
      "failed to convert public key to xonly public key"};
}

if (secp256k1_schnorrsig_verify(
        Secp256k1::context().get(),
        reinterpret_cast<const std::uint8_t *>(
            aggregatedSignature.data()),
        message, message.size(),
        &secp256k1XonlyPublicKeyAggregated) == 0) {
  throw std::runtime_error{"failed to verify signature"};
}


MuSig (and MuSig2, which is what the library you're using implements?) do not support deterministic nonces, though there are other schemes that do.

You say "All information is public except for the complete set of keypairs and partial signatures that contributed to the aggregated signature and aggregated public key." But in your example scenario, really everything is public including all private keys and all private nonce. Can you clarify what is supposed to be public?

@PieterWuille As demonstrated in the illustrative code, when generating nonces using secp256k1_musig_nonce_gen (using the library https://github.com/bitcoin-core/secp256k1), the deterministicValue is explicitly set to a deterministic value, ensuring that the nonces are deterministic. I’m unsure whether the library was intentionally designed to support it being used in this way.

@real-or-random You're correct that the example data includes details for Keypair 1, Keypair 2, and Keypair 3. Apologies for the confusion. I included all the data in case anyone needed it for manual calculations or to explore potential solutions. In the actual scenario, however, only the data for Keypair 1 would be known. I'll update the example to reflect this assumption.

@JohnDeBord As the documentation for the secp256k1_musig_nonce_gen function states "a 32-byte session_secrand32 as explained above. Must be unique to this call to secp256k1_musig_nonce_gen and must be uniformly random". See https://github.com/bitcoin-core/secp256k1/blob/v0.6.0/include/secp256k1_musig.h#L311L335. If you use a deterministic value here, you risk reusing the same value on a retry. If so, the scheme becomes completely insecure (malicious cosigners can learn your private key).
